# QGIS Atlas print composer - Several raster in the same layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression, atlas

I am trying to export an Atlas, with a comparison of maps between 3 periods.
For each period I have a different raster (2008, 2016, 2022).

I found a way to display the right raster, for each map, which is updated on every page of the Atlas.
To do so, I simply wrote the name of the layer I want in the "Layers" options (see image) of each map.

[image: Expression]

I tried this expression:

```
concat ('New_area_2008_HQ_modified', '|', '[T]_STUDY_AREA')
```

But, I can't display the other information (two Shapefile), the same way it is only displayed on the third map (see image below). Green rectangle and multi-colored lines.

[image: Current_situation]

Do you know how I could have these three different maps, vertically aligned, displaying the same information (shapes), except for the raster and which are updated for each page of the Atlas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the issue.

The different layers should be written in the orde we want to display them.
By writing this:

```
concat ('New_area_2008_HQ_modified', '|', '[T]_STUDY_AREA')
```

The raster is on top of the shapefile.

But if I change the order:

```
concat('[T]_STUDY_AREA', '|', 'New_area_2008_HQ_modified')
```

Then it works!